# Side menu randomly not working on Touch for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, menu, ionic-framework, touch

So for some reason that I'm not sure of, my side menu has stopped working on iOS but works perfectly on android and ionic view. Actually i can get it to work on one of my iPads mini v9.2.1 but on my iPhone 6s v9.2.1 and iPad v9.2.1 it doesn't seem to respond when tapping on the hamburger. It works fine in ionic serve but in the iOS simulator it does not. Between versions I didn't even update any code with the menu and now has randomly stopped functioning. I've read some other user posts but they don't seem to relate to the issue in having.

It's an ionic v1 project. I'm not sure if I need to migrate to v2 which I'm not keen to do at this stage.

If anyone has any suggestions to help me I would appreciate it as I'm stuck. Thanks.

```html
<ion-side-menus enable-menu-with-back-views="false">
    <ion-side-menu-content>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-energized">
            <ion-nav-back-button></ion-nav-back-button>
            <ion-nav-buttons side="left">
                <button class="button button-icon button-clear ion-navicon" menu-toggle=""></button>
            </ion-nav-buttons>
        </ion-nav-bar>
        <ion-nav-view name="side-menu21"></ion-nav-view>
    </ion-side-menu-content>
    <ion-side-menu side="left">
        <ion-header-bar class="bar-calm">
            <div class="title">Menu</div>
        </ion-header-bar>
        <ion-content padding="false" class="side-menu-left has-header" <="" ion-content="">
            <ion-list>
                <ion-item href="#/side-menu21/home" menu-close="">Home</ion-item>
                <ion-item href="#/side-menu21/fremantle" menu-close="">Fremantle</ion-item>
                <ion-item href="#/side-menu21/esk" menu-close="">Esk</ion-item>
                <ion-item href="#/side-menu21/melbourne" menu-close="">Melbourne</ion-item>
                <!-- <ion-item href="#/side-menu21/eventinfo" menu-close="">Event Info</ion-item> -->
                <!-- <ion-item href="#/side-menu21/mynotes" menu-close="">My Notes</ion-item> -->
                <!-- <ion-item href="#/side-menu21/tickets" menu-close="">Tickets</ion-item> -->
                <ion-item href="#/side-menu21/photos" menu-close="">Photos</ion-item>
                <ion-item href="#/side-menu21/socialmedia" menu-close="">Social Media</ion-item>
                <ion-item href="#/side-menu21/contact" menu-close="">Contact</ion-item>
                <!-- <ion-item href="#/side-menu21/entertainment" menu-close="">Entertainment</ion-item> -->
                <!-- <ion-item href="#/side-menu21/vendors" menu-close="">Vendors</ion-item> -->

            </ion-list>
        </ion-content>
    </ion-side-menu>
</ion-side-menus>
```